# How to add new schema to existing Visual Studio Database Project?

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio-2013

I'd like to add new schema (like dbo but with different name, ex. Fruit) to database. I'm using database project in Visual Studio 2013. I have an existing database project with tables, schemas, stored procedures, pre and post deployment scripts, etc. Database project is version controlled. I'd like generating publish scripts to work nicely as it did before I added a new schema.

Creating Fruit.schema.sql in *SchemaObjects/Database Level Objects/Security/Schemas* with content

```
CREATE SCHEMA [Fruit]
```

will create schema but won't add Fruit schema folder sub tree in *Schema Objects/Schemas* folder like dbo schema has. Should I create that subtree manually? I suspect there is smarter way to achive this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, create the folder manually. There's no smarter way to do this :-)

Answer (score 18):

In Visual Studio 2017, I can add item => search for schema, and that creates a sql file that includes the line: `create schema [fruit]`.

Then, I can reference  that schema when creating other database objects.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is pretty old, but I thought whoever is looking at this and scratching his/her head - how do I create all these folders automatically? can benefit from this link - [copy folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996649/powershell-copy-folders-w-o-files-files-w-o-folders-or-everything)

so to create a new schema named "mh" you could do
robocopy .\dbo .\mh /e /xf *.*